# vlookup result then move down two cells

Tags: vlookup

I have this vlookup
=VLOOKUP($CJ$1,'situation data'!BU9:BU70,1,false)

what I want to do is be able to grab the result 2 cells down from the original result

vlookup returns x
I would like to find something that after it returns x it goes down and returns 4 and would like to be able to increment it. using the formula bar .

combination of vlookup and Hlookup came to mind but still don't think that would work. because I only need to move down I don't have another reference point.

a
b
x
1
4

Answer (score 2):

The second half of your question is unclear. For the first half, you'd be better served by using INDEX/MATCH.

```
=INDEX('situation data'!BU9:BU70,MATCH($CJ$1,'situation data'!BU9:BU70,0)+2)
```

INDEX/MATCH works just like VLOOKUP, but you can add to the MATCH results to offset the number of rows you want (+2 in this case).